# Could not generate thumbnail from tslib_cObj instance in typo3

Tags: typo3

I have tried following typo-script to generate thumbnail. It is not working for me. 
Please help.

```
$cObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_cObj');
$image_conf['file'] = 'uploads/pics/filename.jpg';
$image_conf['file.']['width'] = $width;
$image_conf['file.']['height'] = $height;    
$newThumb = $cObj->IMAGE($image_conf);
print $newThumb;
```

I want to generate thumbnail from jpg,jpeg,png formats

Comment: Is the image processing in working in general (check the install tool)? Also, in which which context are you trying to run this? In a plugin?

Comment: Yes, i am running this from my custom plug-in.I have enabled gd library from installer tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plugin you can use

```
$this->cObj->IMAGE($image_conf);
```

to scale an image.
As the cObject has some dependencies, an instance of `t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_cObj');` wont be sufficient to scale images.